# Hadoop Mapredce Map output

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Recently I read that map task write its output to the local disk and not to HDFS. When I tried a sample Mapreduce code in pseudo-distributed mode with only map function in it and no reducer , I found the output being written into HDFS.Why is it so? 
Could anyone explain this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high level idea is that the final output of the mapreduce job is written to HDFS so that it can be used for other purposes whereas any intermediate data i.e. the output of the map jobs is written to local (to avoid the overheads in replication of data in hdfs) and this data is then consumed by the reducers for producing the final output

So in this where number of reducers are 0, the output from mappers is the final output and hence written to HDFS.

Comment: After writing the intermediate data to local disk will it be deleted finally after writing them to HDFS ?

Comment: As far as I have known, this data on local disk gets deleted periodically. However if you are running some nested map-reduce jobs, the output of intermediate reduce jobs gets stored in /tmp directory in hadoop and it doesn't get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In normal MapReduce jobs only Reducer outputs are written to HDFS, Map output/intermediate data is written to disk.And the output file in HDFS will be equal to no of reducers.

If we dont have reducers ie  when ***job.setNumReduceTasks()*** set to ***0***. No reducers will run and the map output is written to HDFS and the output files will be equal to no of mappers.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @NeethuPL: Please accept the answer if you find it useful